# send string data from Activity to fragment

Tags: java, android, sqlite, fragment, android-sqlite

I want to send a string from Activity (MainActivity.java) to the to the Fragment (Tozihat.java) and set to the a TextView but it gives an error.
I have checked other topics but I can't find solution of my problem.

code From Database Methode I write id + 1 because the first item position from listView is 0 but the first id is 1 :

```
    public String Tozihat(int id) {
    int id2 = id + 1;
    String query = "SELECT Tozihat FROM tbl_mive WHERE ID ="+id2;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query , null);
    String t;
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    t = cursor.getString(0);

    return t;
}
```

code from my MainActivity.Java

```
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this , ClickActivity.class);

            String t = myDbHelper.Tozihat(position);
            Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
            Tozihat tozihat = new Tozihat();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.textViewTozihat , tozihat, null);
            bundle.putString("Tozihat", t );
            tozihat.setArguments(bundle);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

code from my Faragment (Tozihat.java)

```
public class Tozihat extends Fragment{

TextView textViewTozihat;
DataBaseHelper myDbHelper;
String Tozihat;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tozihat, container, false);



    myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(getActivity());

    textViewTozihat = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewTozihat);

    Tozihat = getArguments().getString("Tozihat");

    textViewTozihat.setText(Tozihat);

    return view;

}
```

please help me!

Comment: Whats you MainActivity Code?? Why are you calling `startActivity` and .`commit` at same time?? Can you please explain this?

Comment: Your problem is that you put fragment in activity and at the same time starting new activity. Tozihat fragment not already yet transacted in MainActivity. Here is logic exception

Comment: I have never worked with fragments I did not know that. i delete intent but Is still forced stop

Comment: Read [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/117838/introduction-to-android-fragments-tutorial)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below code inside listview itemclick listner in activity:

```
 Tozihat gTozihat  = new Tozihat().newInstance("Data");
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.textViewTozihat, gTozihat).commit();
```

Inside your Fragment :

```
 private static final String TYPE = "DATA_KEY";
public static  Tozihat newInstance(String type) {
         Tozihat fragment = new  Tozihat();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(TYPE, type);

        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
```

Comment: it was error...

Comment: plse check the edited code

Comment: thanks but it was force stop!!!